# What is Gitlab host URL in Jenkins configuration for Gitlab?

Tags: macos, jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to configure Jenkins to work with Gitlab.

Currently, I have set *Gitlab host URL* in the Jenkins *configure* page as https://gitlab.example.com, which results in the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 403
>   Problem accessing /descriptorByName/com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.connection.GitLabConnectionConfig/checkUrl. Reason:
>
> Forbidden

As I understand it, the *Gitlab host URL* is specified under external_url in the */etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb* file. However, this file doesn't exist on my local machine. I believe it's created when gitlab is installed but I am unsure it is possible to install gitlab on a mac as I have thus far been unable to find any instructions as to how to do so.

Where would I find the correct gitlab host URL in this case?